# why i get object object error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax request to change the value of some php session variable I still get object object error no matter how I changed the code :

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#facebook_img').live('click',function(){
        login_condetion=1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'facebook_login_condition_variable.php',
            data:{login_condetion:login_condetion},
            success: function()
            {
                alert('test');
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest);  
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

facebook_login_condition_variable.php :

```
   <?php 
    $temp = $_POST['login_condetion'];
    if(!empty($temp) && $temp != 0)
    {
       $_SESSION['do_not_allow_auto_facebook_login'] = 1;
    }
    else    
    {
        $_SESSION['do_not_allow_auto_facebook_login'] = 0;  
    }
    ?>
```

I tried a lot of ajax form but same error and I get nothing when I alert `responseText` I do not understand why I still get that error ? I hope to find some help here thank u

Comment: `login_condetion` != `login_condition`

Comment: I fix this syntax error but nothing changed same error :(

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error... It means that the variables you try to alert are objects.

If you want to see the content of it, replace `alert` by `console.log` and see the javascript console of your browser...

Comment: i would recommend "console.dir()" for looking at objects

Comment: What I should pass to the `console.log` or `console.dir` my success function do not get any value or array or obj back ?

Comment: Because you will see the error message in your console...
It's not you success function you need to log but XMLHttpRequest, textStatus and errorThrown as :
`console.dir(XMLHttpRequest); `
`console.dir(textStatus);  `
`console.dir(errorThrown);`